# AWS SDK - purpose of async configuration SdkAdvancedAsyncClientOption.FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

What is the purpose of asyncConfiguration  `SdkAdvancedAsyncClientOption.FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR`?
in which use cases should we use it?

from java doc on `FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR`, I see: `Configure the executor that should be used to complete the CompletableFuture that is returned by the service clients.` I thought that subsequent calls on `CompletableFuture` of async result will be executed on executor passed in `FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR`, but it’s not.

```
ClientAsyncConfiguration.Builder asyncConfig = ClientAsyncConfiguration.builder()
        .advancedOption(SdkAdvancedAsyncClientOption.FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR, customExecutor);

SnsAsyncClient.builder()
        .asyncConfiguration(asyncConfig.build())
        .build();
```

Example of async request:

```
snsAsyncClient.publish(publishRequest).thenApplyAsync(..);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS SDK async requests return `CompletableFuture`. Invocation of `thenApply(..)` and `whenComplete(..)` on returned `CompletableFuture` instance by default will be executed on threads like `sdk-async-response-0-X`.
The idea of async configuration `SdkAdvancedAsyncClientOption.FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR` is to provide thread pool executor, which will be used for subsequent calls on `CompletableFuture` like `thenApply(..)` and `whenComplete(..)`. This executor will not be applied for methods like `thenApplyAsync` and `whenCompleteAsync` due to `CompletableFuture` implementation (if executor not passed into `thenApplyAsync(..)`, it will be used by default `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`, or we could pass custom executor as a second method argument).

```
snsAsyncClient.publish(publishRequest)
        .thenApply(..)
        .whenComplete(..);
```

code inside `thenApply` and `whenComplete` will be processed on configured executor from `SdkAdvancedAsyncClientOption.FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR`.